# Why this code causes SIGSEGV (gcc compiler, Android NDK toolchain under cygwin)?

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault

The `TryIt()` function causes a SIGSEGV error but only with GCC and not with Visual C:

```
string strs[] = 
{
 "str1",
 "str2",
 "str3",
 ""
};


void Tryit()
{
    int cnt = 0;
    while ( strs[cnt] != "" )
       cnt++;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to find exactly which line causes the SIGSEV?

Comment: As far as I can tell that code is correct (and doesn't crash compiled with g++ 4.7.2 x86_64 on Linux); are you sure that the problem lies there?

Comment: The code you've posted is perfectly fine on its own—the problem lies in some code you're not showing us.  Try to reduce it to a [short, self-contained, complete, compilable example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Sorry, i didn't posted all the code and i think i have found what is causing SEGV. The TryIt() function is a piece of code that belongs to the constructor of an object. The object is defined at global scope, as the strs array. Maybe the strs array is created *after* the object constructor is called and this causes SIGSEV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as posted is correct, assuming `TryIt()` is called after `strs` was constructed. Since you mention that it is called from the constructor of a global object, it is probably called before `strs` is constructed. The work-around is to wrap `strs` inside a function and call this function to get the base address of the array:

```
std::string* strs() {
    static std::string rc[] p {
         ...
    };
    return rc;
}
```